# I am uploading image to Firebase Storage and then I need to add the image URL as text in Firebase Database

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database

***I have model class its name is (Restaurants) I want to add restaurants details like address and name with an image for restaurants, and upload image in Firebase storage and details in Firebase database then I need to add the image URL as text in Firebase database***

```
 String Res_Name = txtAddResName.getText().toString();
                String Res_Address = txtResAddress.getText().toString();
                String Res_TimeOpne = txtOpenTime.getText().toString();
                String Res_CloseTime = closeTime.getText().toString();
                String Res_imageURL = "" ;//i need to get image URL here
```

//Here I wase upload the image

```
public void uploadImg() {
        if (filePath != null) {
            pd.show();

            //for random name image
            StorageReference childRef = storageRef.child(System.currentTimeMillis() + "_mas.jpg");

            //uploading the image
            UploadTask uploadTask = childRef.putFile(filePath);

            uploadTask.addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                    pd.dismiss();
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Upload successful", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                    pd.dismiss();
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Upload Failed -> " + e, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Select an image", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once upload is completed, in `onSuccess` you have to get the download url from Firebase Storage like this

```
childRef.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
        // Got the download uri
    }
}).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
    @Override
    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
        // Handle any errors
    }
});
```

once you got the download uri you can simply update the `Res_imageURL` like so in onSuccess of download uri task.

```
dbRef.child("Res_imageURL").setValue(uri.toString())
```